# Using MapKit or Google Maps iOS SDK without labels

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I am working on an app and need to embed a map that will display some information using an overlay.  Due to the nature and amount of information, I would like the map to not have any specific detail other than the country outlines and my overlay data (no roads/buildings/labels/etc).  Basically with Apples Mapkit I would like to only display the base layer.  I can't figure out how to do this though, apart from creating my own map tiles which will force Apples tiles not to be rendered.

I considered Google Maps but ran into the same issue as the iOS SDK does not appear to handle the setOptions method.

Without using something like MapBox, can anyone see a simple way to make this work?  Ideally using MapKit as it supports all the features I require, seems to render faster than Google Maps and doesn't restrict the number of request made.

Sorry if this is obvious, I have done a trawl of the documentation myself but came up with little that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 7, you are now able to put arbitrary overlays under the labels layer if you like. Check out the API like `-[MKMapView addOverlays:level:]` and the `MKOverlayLevel` options. But that's about as far as you can get without something like custom map layers and the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am hoping an update to the Google SDK will bring the setOptions functionality back.  I will hold this question open for awhile to see if this happens.